# Most concise, Pythonic way to represent a null byte as a binary (bytes) string in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I needed to add some padding to a bytes string. This is what I came up with:

```
if padding_len > 0:
    data += bytes.fromhex('00') * padding_len
```

Is there a nicer way of representing a null byte in Python 3 than `bytes.fromhex('00')`?

Comment: Use bytes literal: `b'\0'`. `bytes(padding_len)` will give you *padding_len* bytes (filled with 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('00') == b'\x00'
True
>>> b'\x00' * 10
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

EDIT:

As hobbs points out in a comment below, it is certainly possible to use `b'\0'` instead of `b'\x00'` and as j-f-sebastian points out, it is not confusing in this instance.

But I wouldn't do it, anyway.  It certainly works *in this context* (and it saves you two characters, if that's important).  It will even work in the most common *other* context, where you are building strings for C and putting a null byte at the end.

But in the most general case, it can lead to confusion, because the compiler's interpretation of `b'\0'` is *highly data dependent*.  In other words, it changes according to what comes after that zero.

```
>>> b'\0ABC' == b'\00ABC'
True
>>> b'\0ABC' == b'\000ABC'
True
>>> b'\0ABC' == '\0000ABC'
False
```

If you are debugging late at night when not all your brain cells are functioning, it is highly frustrating to have the length of a string change because you replaced a character in the string.  All you have to do to avoid this is to always use two extra characters.  It doesn't matter whether you use `\x00` (hexadecimal) or `\000` octal -- both of those will work properly no matter the value of the following character.

Comment: Or `b"\0"` for that matter.

Comment: That works, but personally I wouldn't go there, unless the goal is to generate more questions.  It's confusing that `b'\0x' == b'\x00x'` but `b'\01' == b'\x01'`

Comment: `b'\0'` is *not* confusing for a Python programmer.